# Given the following array, how would I write an ES6 expression to return all the first names

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

```
const ducks = [
   { first: 'Stan', last: 'duck' },
   { first: 'Steve', last: 'duck' },
   { first: 'Kyle', last: 'duck' },
];
```

I've tried

```
const ducks = [
  { first: 'Stan', last: 'duck' },
  { first: 'Steve', last: 'duck' },
  { first: 'Kyle', last: 'duck' },
];

console.log(ducks, [3]);
```

This returns way too much:

```
[...]                                     [3]
  0: {first: "Stan", last: "duck"}          0: 3
  1: {first: "Steve", last: "duck"}         length: 1
  2: {first: "Kyle", last: "duck"}          __proto__: Array(0)
  length: 3
  __proto__: Array(0)
```

need it to return  the names `"Stan"`, `"Steve"`, and `"Kyle"` only.

Comment: ducks.map(object => object.first) // ["Stan", "Steve", "Kyle"] or ducks.map(object => object.first).join()  // "Stan,Steve,Kyle"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **Array**'s `map()` like the following:

```js
const ducks = [
    { first: 'Stan', last: 'duck' },
    { first: 'Steve', last: 'duck' },
    { first: 'Kyle', last: 'duck' }
];
 
let res = ducks.map((item) => item.first);
 
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 8):

You're just logging the array and another array containing the number 3. Your code is equivalent to this (though separated on two lines in the console):

```
console.log(ducks);
console.log([3]);
```

You should use a `map` function to get an array of all first names like:

```
let firstNames = ducks.map(duck => duck.first);
console.log(firstNames);
```

And if you are interested in just logging the names, then use `forEach` like this:

```
ducks.forEach(duck => console.log(duck.first));
```